# Laravel Session read issue with subdomain and site system

Tags: php, laravel, session, server-configuration

I have issue with Laravel ( v 5.0.34 ) install .
I have subdomain laravel.mydomain.com 
and that is installed in site where path is home/site123/web/ which is linked to /var/www/site123 directory (symlink)

the problem is i was able to install laravel but once we do successful login it redirect us back on login page .

i have set my domin in config as ".mydomin.com" and session is getting saved in database but still its not redirecting properly

```
$this->middleware('auth'); // while authenticating session not getting found
```

above statement redirecting me back. i tried printing session in constructor and its there .

i tried setting

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

or

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
```

or

```
SESSION_DRIVER=array
```

its not working

Thanks for your help

Comment: When diagnosing redirects (or session things) I find https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar an invaluable resource. It will tell you immediately if you're having session trouble or a redirect issue or whatever by just looking at it. Obviously not for an in-production site, but it does respect your .env setting for "debug", set it to false and debugbar goes away.

Comment: If the session is persisted in the database, can you confirm that the cookie is created in your browser?

Comment: Hi swatkins . the cookie is being created but its not able to read . i tried same environment on openshift.com (free hosting)  its working fine .